# How to forward (inside a container) requests from 0.0.0.0 to 127.0.0.1

Tags: docker, linux-networking, docker-compose, docker-networking

Looking for a solution on how to forward the requests from `0.0.0.0:9222 --> 127.0.0.1:9222` inside a container

I am using a docker container with `google-chrome-stable` installed for running visual testing.

```
root@6bb8678b29f5:/# google-chrome-stable --version
Google Chrome 114.0.5735.90
```

Maybe that's [totally justified](https://embracethered.com/blog/posts/2020/chrome-spy-remote-control/) that `google-chrome` listens on different addresses when lunching from command line without `--headless`, but this is preventing me from tracing the tests when writing them. So i need sometimes to turn-of the `--headless` for debugging purposes.

However, when not using `--headless` switch, then `google-chrome` is ignoring the other: `--remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0` switch completely and is starting the `DevTools` and listens on `127.0.0.1` for connection, by default. Then the test runner fails to connect to the `DevTools`.

```
Connecting to 172.22.0.13:9222... failed: Connection refused.
```

So my thought was to set-up port forwarding for DEV environment, but i can't really get it working

I tried this:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9222 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:9222
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 0.0.0.0 --dport 9222 -j SNAT --to-source 127.0.0.1
```

... the request is not immediately refused but still not connecting.

```
--2023-06-05 13:14:16--  http://172.22.0.13:9222/json/version
Connecting to 172.22.0.13:9222... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.

--2023-06-05 13:16:28--  (try: 2)  http://172.22.0.13:9222/json/version
Connecting to 172.22.0.13:9222... failed: Connection timed out.
Retrying.
```

I was hoping somebody with more experience in this would give me a hint here :)

Thanks !!
.

**EDIT**

I find myself in the situation "2" when `chrome-stable` is launched inside container without `--headless`, binding (by default) on `127.0.0.1` address instead of `0.0.0.0`

[image: Visual diagram of the setup]

```
root@c877116fd92a:/# netstat -tuln
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State      
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:9222          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:35045        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5900            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 :::5900                 :::*                    LISTEN     
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:52971        0.0.0.0:*                          
udp        0      0 224.0.0.251:5353        0.0.0.0:*
```

```
root@0442b7974e78:/# iptables -L -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
root@0442b7974e78:/# iptables -t nat -L -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.1            tcp dpt:9222

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER_OUTPUT  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11          

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER_POSTROUTING  all  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11          

Chain DOCKER_OUTPUT (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DNAT       tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11           tcp dpt:53 to:127.0.0.11:44889
DNAT       udp  --  0.0.0.0/0            127.0.0.11           udp dpt:53 to:127.0.0.11:41070

Chain DOCKER_POSTROUTING (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
SNAT       tcp  --  127.0.0.11           0.0.0.0/0            tcp spt:44889 to::53
SNAT       udp  --  127.0.0.11           0.0.0.0/0            udp spt:41070 to::53
```

.

.

.

---

**More details** on the output, when launching `google-chrome`

```
root@6bb8678b29f5:/# /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-sandbox --window-size="1920,1080" --disable-dev-shm-usage --no-startup-window --no-first-run --start-maximized --disable-extensions --disable-infobars --user-data-dir=/var/tmp/chrome --log-level=3
[737:737:0605/110543.181892:ERROR:browser_dm_token_storage_linux.cc(100)] Error: /etc/machine-id contains 0 characters (32 were expected).

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9222/devtools/browser/3db57e4b-403f-42cc-a385-b4d6b031a753
```

```
root@6bb8678b29f5:/# /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --headless --disable-gpu --remote-debugging-address=0.0.0.0 --remote-debugging-port=9222 --no-sandbox --window-size="1920,1080" --disable-dev-shm-usage --no-startup-window --no-first-run --start-maximized --disable-extensions --disable-infobars --user-data-dir=/var/tmp/chrome --log-level=3 

DevTools listening on ws://0.0.0.0:9222/devtools/browser/7448953b-8da1-4d13-8621-91ebbec8d3f4
```

Answer (score 0):

Docker containers has some port forarding/NATing that can help automate this.

But if you want to do this the hard way...

The address `0.0.0.0` is not used in general as source address (e.g. DHCP discovery is using it). When a service listens on `0.0.0.0` means it is listaning on all available interfaces, but is actually listening only on the IP addressess configured on the local interfaces.

In Netfilter firewall you can foward/NAT all TCP+UDP traffic with the destination a specific port to another IP:port pair. The incoming traffic that has the destination a local interface, will not go trough `(PRE|POST)ROUTING` chains/tables, but via `INPUT`.

For debugging, with `sudo iptables -L -nv` you can see how many times a Netfilter rule was matched.

Don't be affraid to use 2 `tcpdump` commands,  one for the incoming packet and one for the NAT-ed packet and filter for specifics that you expect (in this case the destination IP:port should chnage).

Comment: Thanks for your answer @mircea-vutcovici, my container is based on `ubuntu:focal-20230301` I tried to open the port in the `INPUT`: `iptables -t nat -A INPUT -p --dport 9222 -j ACCEPT` but without luck :(